# how to call function on new created _blank tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I copy page to new tab, and call `.ready(function(){});` on new created tab?

```
$("#copyTab").live("click", function () {
     var url = window.location.pathname;
     window.open(url, '_blank');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add scripting to the new page. So you will have to be in control of the page that you are opening.

Add this to the new page before the `</body>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // code here
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please add any example?